# What does it mean Band or Non-band in an iPhone specs?

Tags: iphone

NB30 stands for Non band 30, what is this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't repost your questions! If you have any new information, edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 6S exists in basically two versions:

Models A1687 and A1688 has support for LTE bands 1-5, 7-8, 12-13, 17-20 and 25-29

Models A1633 and A1634 has support for LTE bands 1-5, 7-8, 12-13, 17-20 and 26-30.

The extra band 30 is a special AT&T band. The iPhone supporting that band were sold by certain dealers in the US.

The NB30 on your iPhone description just means that you iPhone does not support LTE band 30.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @AntonioMS Please mark the question as answered if you've got the information you need.